# Attempting to install ubuntu, and it gets stuck

Tags: system-installation

I attemtped to install Ubuntu, but didnt work so I tried to install Linux Mint. Both times it gets stuck on the following:

```
cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

I am unsure what this means, or what I am doing wrong.

I have more than 4 partitions, could this be the cause?

Also I should talk about where I am trying to install. My only working computer is a Macbook pro, and I have a separate computer build. I have a SSD that I am attempting to install linux on, which will be the hard drive for said computer build, but I am attempting to do the installation through my Macbook pro by connecting the hard drive to my Macbook pro.

EDIT: I should have said that i dont have a spare USB, so I am trying to install from one partition to another.

Comment: You might have an easier time if you don't use the Macbook at all. Why are you using the Macbook in the first place?

Comment: The Macbook is my only working computer, so i am using this to install ubuntu onto the external SSD

Answer (score 0):

It's not your partitions. I have five and Ubuntu installed. This happened to me too on the 2nd computer I installed Ubuntu on. The answer is based on personal experience, so it may be inaccurate. I'm assuming you're installing the desktop environment, so try these:

1. Right click "Details" in the installation window. Leave it for a minute, see if anything comes up. If it's doing stuff, leave it for awhile. It took about an hour for Ubuntu to format /dev/sda1 with ext4 for me.
2. Doing nothing? Take disk out, turn computer off, put disk back in, turn on. Shouldn't restart installation, at least it didn't for me.

Comment: 1. Im not sure I understand this entirely. I do format the partition that i want to install ubuntu to, to ext4. 2. take disk out? what disk? Please see EDIT thanks.